# UIPopoverController on table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I have used a UIPopoverController on my toolbar item.. when the user clicked the button it shows a list of items in a table view.. please screenshot below..

[image]

Question is how do you focus on the table view on the popup and allow the user to scroll to cell..?

Thanks,

link

Comment: What do you mean by focus? The tableview should be scrollable as is...

Comment: hi @ChrisWagner, thanks for the quick response.. yes, you're correct the tableview is scrollable.. but the problem is i have another tableview aside from the popup table view.. so, here's my design.. i have created a xib file.. under that xib it has a table view and a toobar and uibarbuttonitem.. if you clicked an buttonitem, i have to populate a list of items using another tableview.. the scroll works on the first tableview not on the popup..

Comment: i have used this as a reference http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial

Comment: I am still having a hard time understanding your design/goal. Can you elaborate further?

Comment: the goal is to allow the user to filter the content of the tableview by location.. simple as that..

Comment: i have used this http://www.raywenderlich.com/1056/ipad-for-iphone-developers-101-uipopovercontroller-tutorial to display available locations and add a location Picker

Comment: So, upon selecting a row on the popover you want to apply a filter to another tableview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so now that I better understand your question. Your `UITableViewDelegate` for the tableview in your popover should implement `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. In this method you would do the following.

1. Determine which row was selected using `indexPath`
2. Based on the selected row, filter your datasource for the other tableview and call `[myOtherTableView reloadData]` directly, post a notification, execute a block, or have another layer of delegation
3. Dismiss your `UIPopoverController`

Comment: Thanks, will implement this and provide some feedback later.. Thanks again @Chris Wagner..